# Accessing "this" from a Helper method in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Helper method that I need to use across multiple views. In an attempt to accomplish this, I tried to implement the approach shown by Scott Guthrie here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx. For the sake of reference, my helper method looks like the following:

```
  @helper MyMethod(string parameter)
  {
    MyNamespace.MyClass.HelperMethod(this.Request, parameter)
  }
```

As you can see, I need to get access to the HttpRequestBase object associated with the view.  The code works fine if I define the method at the top of _Layout.cshtml. However, I need to use it in other views. So, as mentioned, I used the approach highlighted by scottgu. Unfortunately, I get a runtime error now that says:

"CS0026: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer"

How can I get over this hump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the HttpRequestBase object you need, try passing in `HttpContext.Current.Request` instead of `this.Request`.